# Is there a way to avoid the so called "resort fee"?

Tags: hotels, fees-and-charges, resorts

Many nicer hotels are getting away with a so called resort fee these days. Basically, this is an additionally daily charge usually between $25 and $70 after the room rate and taxes. I hear roughly the same excuses for this charge nearly every time I ask about it. They typically say something like "This fee covers all the amenities that the resort supplies, such as the pool, tennis courts, turn down service, and in-room wifi." I usually respond "Well, if I don't use those then I don't think I should be charged for them." That has never worked.

Honestly, I don't buy it. Some times I'm already paying well over $250 a night at these places, so it really angers me that there's an additionally daily charge for services I don't even use.

I've never really pressed the issue at the front desk. Would that even be fruitful? Is there a way around this silly (and relatively new*) surcharge?

---

*As little as 15 years ago this was not very common. It seems to me that it started with the really fancy places (like $500+ per night) about 25 years ago then as trickled down to the lesser hotels. It seems like if they have a pool, wifi, and something like a tennis court, they feel justified in charging for this.

Comment: I checked the [help] and this seemed like it would be on-topic. Sorry if it's not.

Comment: [It seems the FTC did have something to say about it](http://www.cnn.com/2012/11/28/travel/hotels-resort-fees-warning/index.html)

Comment: Is this a US only phenomenon?

Comment: Book instead at an honest hotel that doesn't charge the fees?

Comment: @Grzenio I've been outside the US a few times, but someone else was covering the bill. All except one were over 10 years ago too. In other words, yes, it's common now in the US especially in destination towns (e.g. Vegas, Orlando, Honolulu/Maui), but I don't know about other countries.

Comment: Hopefully it will not spread around the world, I really hate these kind of hidden fees.

Comment: Five years later, I find one of the best things about Airbnb is that the exact price of your stay is entirely transparent. That's one major reason I stay Airbnb most of the time now. Hotels can suck it.

Comment: A year and a half later and now I'm a host, Airbnb is trying to convince me to hide their fees charged behind my nightly price. I guess they figure guests question why a simple booking website needs 15% of the total paid.

Comment: Another few years later, I'm making a direct booking website and made last season's bookings more than 75% via VRBO instead of ABNB. *Airbnb* can suck it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**.  When you're booking, the resort fee is always disclosed somewhere in the small print, and a [class action lawsuit](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/09/11/your-money/when-hotels-add-resort-fees-to-pricelines-price.html) a while back concluded that this is enough.  You'd only have a case if you can plausibly claim that you were *not* made aware of this at any time in the booking process.

That said, there's one way to avoid them: **don't stay at hotels that charge resort fees**, and maybe they'll eventually get the message.

Comment: "don't stay at hotels that charge resort fees" easier said than done. More and more of them are doing it now.

Comment: Hotels are under interesting legal requirements, compared to other industries. I kind of feel like the resort fee thing is a loophole of some kind.

Comment: @fredsbend - Add on service charges are not loopholes nor are they unheard of.  Book a tour through a European company and there is often a "booking" or "administrative" fee of 25 Euro on top of the tour price.  Buy a new car and there is a several hundred dollar "dealer prep" fee, for what - washing the car.  As long as the fee is disclosed during the buying process, it is legitimate.  They could bury the fee in the overall cost, but with all the price comparison websites, business want to present a lower base price for marketing, so make many costs extra.

Comment: It can be very hard to tell which places do and don't charge them.  I've spent hours scouring a hotel website finding no mention of any fee & made a reservation only to find a sizeable fee charged on arrival.  It doesn't need to be announced or findable in advance if the hotel has a small sign posted on the front desk in the lobby, that one could theoretically walk into.  If a guest happens to be from a distant place and it's not worth the trip to check that in advance, that's the guest's fault for deciding the extra trip wasn't worth the expense.

Comment: This answer is out of date. Turns out almost nobody agrees with the class action lawsuit result, including the credit card companies. https://www.frommers.com/tips/hotel-news/how-to-get-out-of-paying-a-hotels-resort-feeit-can-be-done